# Can not transliterate strings with CP850 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

For my Blog App I use FriendlyId to generate slugs.

In **irb** post creation process following message appears:

```
ArgumentError (Can not transliterate strings with CP850 encoding)
```

I found out that the error appears because of a space between words in the title only, so it probably has something to do with **friendly_id**.

I develop on Windows 10

```
Encoding.default_internal = #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Encoding.default_external = #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Encoding.locale_charmap = "CP850"
```

I would like to use FriendlyId but also be able to use spaces in post title. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of spaces do you have in the titles? Are these `0x20` spaces only?

Comment: `string.bytes` delivers `32` in decimal, which ist `20` in hex, so yes should be only the 0x20s